# ARM Fixed Virtual Platforms (FVP) and ARMv8.4-a support

Tags: arm, emulation, armv8, fvp

ARM offers emulators for development at [Fixed Virtual Platforms (FVPs)](https://developer.arm.com/products/system-design/fixed-virtual-platforms). ARM also announced [ARMv8.4-a](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/introducing-2017s-extensions-to-the-arm-architecture), which provides hardware acceleration for cryptographic algorithms, including SHA2-512, SHA3, SM3 and SM4. I have some C++ code I want t port to the new instructions.

I need access to a FVP or machine with ARMv8.4-a. I don't believe there is any silicon in the field with ARMv8.4-a at the moment. I think that means FVPs are my only choice at the moment.

My question is, do the FVP's support ARMv8.4?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> My question is, do the FVP's support ARMv8.4?

According to Barry Spotts of ARM FVP team:

> Our ARM AEMv8 FVP is free and can be downloaded from
>   https://developer.arm.com/products/system-design/fixed-virtual-platforms
>
> It does support ARM 8.4 extensions. Linaro build does support our AEMv8 FVP.

It looks like [QEMU added ARMv8.4-a support](https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=summary) in February 2018 so the instructions can be emulated.